# Deploying Shiny App shiny-server issue

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am having an issue deploying a shiny app via `shiny-server` on ubuntu 14 (on chromebook).

I followed all of the setup steps for `shiny-server`, and the app appeared to deploy OK on my computer.

I run `sudo shiny-server` in the command prompt and this appears:

```
[2016-01-10 14:52:36.348] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.4.1.759 (Node.js v0.10.40)
[2016-01-10 14:52:36.351] [INFO] shiny-server - Using pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid
[2016-01-10 14:52:36.352] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2016-01-10 14:52:36.410] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2016-01-10 14:52:36.414] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
```

I run the command `sudo ifconfig` to get my server IP address, and the site runs on my computer at: http://my_ip_address:3838/sample-apps/hello/.

However, when I try to go to this link at another computer in my house, the website does not load.

Note*: The thing I did to try to fix it was to configure my server's firewall to allow inbound TCP connections on port 3838, which I think Idid.

When I type `sudo ufw status` into command prompt, I get:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3838/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3838                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
3838/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3838                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Did you try ping and telnet to that ip address from the other host?

Comment: Don't you only have to access the port itself?

Comment: I just to ping the IP address from the other computer, and nothing is sent back. I am thinking the issue may be related to the ping issue. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
my_ip_address:3838/hello/
```

instead of

```
my_ip_address:3838/sample-apps/hello/
```

If you check the content of `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` and it says `directory_index on;` you should be able to browse to `my_ip_address:3838` and see a directory listing and at least a welcome page.

Comment: What if this renders, but it's sort of "broken". My app appears to load, but the graph and table that should be output never appear and it turns gray after ~5sec. [This is what I see](https://imgur.com/a/nJAp1) at the welcome/index. It also loads, but the apps themselves fail! It's like there's some issue receiving the output with my corporate firewall settings.